# How to return output of Javascript to python?

Tags: python

I wanted to create a python file say main.py that when i run it it will run my index.html here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Speech API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button  class="talk">Talk</button>
    <h3  class="content"></h3>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my HTML file there is a button when I click it it will listen to my microphone and listen to what I talk and automatically recognize it. However, after It will run I want to automatically return the **recognized words** "event.results[current][0].transcript " back to python for printing and do some NLP for my specific application. Here is my JS code:

======app.js

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.talk');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

const SpeechRecognition = window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.onstart = function (){
console.log('voice is activated on the microphone');
}

recognition.onresult = function(event){
    //console.log(event);
    var current = event.resultIndex;
    var transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
    content.textContent = transcript;
    console.log( event.results[current][0].transcript);
    console.log( transcript);
}

//add listerner

btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
    recognition.start();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you want this to work? Are you expecting, for example, that somebody goes to your website, the javascript runs, and then the output from the javascript is used by a Python script on the user's computer? What if the user doesn't have Python installed? What if the user doesn't have (or want) your Python script?

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript runs in the browser and knows nothing about the server-side python script that generated it.

If you want to send data back to the server for processing, you should provide that service through a web API, which the Javascript calls.